# Laravel: Paginating In Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my blade, I have:

```
<?php 
    $items = $collection->paginate(10);
    dd($collection->paginate(10)); 
?>
```

The `dd()` logs as:

```
array:6 [▼
  "page_size" => 10
  "current_page" => 1
  "current_offset" => 0
  "pages" => 2.0
  "items" => 19
  "next" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

I try to then render in the blade `{{ $items-links() }}` to show a page counter at the bottom and I get the error

> Call to a member function `links()` on array

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using? Also, how are you getting the value for `$collections`?

Comment: In your controller how are you making the query?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination doesn't work on collections.

You might try to write a custom method for that, like here:

https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/3ce756322702331fdf2bf414fea27bcb

Comment: Explain your question? what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.8

in controller

```
public function index(){
   $items = Items::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate();
   return view('index',['items'=>$items]);
}
```

in blade

```
{{ $items }}
```